# Fusion of 3 Lists

Tags: python, algorithm

I've been struggling with one algorithm for a long time now.

Input :

- 3 lists of string : L1, L2 and L3
- 3 lists of pairs containing indexes of two of the 3 lists : P12, P13, P23

Output :
One List containing all strings grouped according to lists of pairs. **The order of the result doesn't matters.**

One example :

```
L1 = ["toto", "tata"]
L2 = ["tutu", "vincent"]
L3 = ["georges", "Jean-Eude", "Pikachu"]
P12 = [(0,1)]
P13 = [(0,1)]
P23 = [(1,0),(1,1)]
algorithm()
S = ["toto vincent georges Jean-Eude", "tata", "tutu", "Pikachu"]
```

explanations :

With P12 "toto" et "vincent" are grouped

With P13 "toto" et "Jean-Eude" must be grouped, but because "toto" and "vincent" are already grouped, it's "toto vincent Jean-Eude"

With P23:
(1,0) "georges" is grouped with the 3 others
(1,1) No changes

Another example

```
T1 = ["toto", "tata"]
T2 = ["tutu"]
T3 = ["georges"]
P12 = [(1,0)]
P13 = [(0,0)]
P23 = [(0,0)]
Output = ["Toto tata tutu georges"]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would see it as connected components graph problem.

```
from collections import deque # bfs

def bfs(adj_l, i, comp):
    """Performs a Breadth First Search from node i on the graph given by adjacency list, filling the components list
. Returns the nodes of the component."""

    l=[i]
    queue = deque([i])
    comp[i] = i
    while queue:
        j = queue.popleft()
        for neighbor in adj_l[j]:
            if comp[neighbor] is None:
                queue.append(neighbor)
                comp[neighbor] = i # update the component
                l.append(neighbor)
    return l

def connectedcomponents(adj_l):
    """Returns the connected components (list of list of nodes) for the graph given by adjency list."""

    n = len(adj_l)

    comp = [None]*n
    ll=[]
    for i in range(n):
        if comp[i] is None:
            ll.append(bfs(adj_l, i, comp))

    return ll

def graph_operations(L1, L2, L3, P12, P13, P23):
    l=L1+L2+L3
    v=[[] for _ in l]
    for i,j in P12:
        v[i].append(j+len(L1))
        v[j+len(L1)].append(i)
    for i,j in P13:
        v[i].append(j+len(L1)+len(L2))
        v[j+len(L1)+len(L2)].append(i)
    for i,j in P23:
        v[i+len(L1)].append(j+len(L1)+len(L2))
        v[j+len(L1)+len(L2)].append(i+len(L1))

    ll = connectedcomponents(v)

    ll = [[l[i] for i in li] for li in ll]

    return ll

L1 = ["toto", "tata"]
L2 = ["tutu", "vincent"]
L3 = ["georges", "Jean-Eude", "Pikachu"]
P12 = [(0,1)]
P13 = [(0,1)]
P23 = [(1,0),(1,1)]

print graph_operations(L1, L2, L3, P12, P13, P23)

L1 = ["toto", "tata"]
L2 = ["tutu"]
L3 = ["georges"]
P12 = [(1,0)]
P13 = [(0,0)]
P23 = [(0,0)]

print graph_operations(L1, L2, L3, P12, P13, P23)
```

The complexity is linear.